# Docker container parameters connect to terraform job

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform

Hello I have the following docker container definition

```
FROM temp_base_image_name_for_post
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y python3 \
 && apt-get install -y python3-pip \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
 && pip3 install boto3

ENV INSTALL_PATH /docker-flowcell-restore
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY /src/* $INSTALL_PATH/src/

ENTRYPOINT python3 src/main.py
```

My terraform module points to this container and has a parameter called --object_key

the module submission is getting the parameters correctly, but it is not being populated in my docker for my python script. How do I modify my current docker image definition in order to get my arguments that are passed into my terraform definition?

Comment: Can you also post the `.tf` file that invokes this?

Comment: No problem posting the terraform module.

Comment: The error comes from the parameter syntax, but I have tried several implementations and all have failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for future reference the fix was

```
FROM temp_base_image_name_for_post
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y python3 \
 && apt-get install -y python3-pip \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
 && pip3 install boto3

ENV INSTALL_PATH /docker-flowcell-restore
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY /src/* $INSTALL_PATH/src/

ENTRYPOINT python3 src/main.py
```

to

```
FROM temp_base_image_name_for_post
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y python3 \
 && apt-get install -y python3-pip \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
 && pip3 install boto3

ENV INSTALL_PATH /docker-flowcell-restore
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY /src/* $INSTALL_PATH/src/

**ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "src/main.py"]**
```